# Which is the best way to pass data to a callback function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I can't find the right term relating to this thing, so I decided to write a question.

I have this function:

```
var methods = {

    login: function(callback){

        $someCustomService
            .login() // This returns $http
            .success(function(data){

                // callback(true, data); --- doing this without using 'return' also works
                return callback(true, data);
            })
            .error(function(data){

                return callback(false, data);

            })

    }

};
```

Call the function:

```
$anotherCustomService.login(function(success, data){

    if(success){
        alert('Success');
    }else{
        alert('Fail');
    }

    console.log(data);

});
```

The line `return callback(true, data);` works just fine, but if I changed it to `callback(true, data);` without using `return` it also works. Now I'm confused whether what to use.

**EDIT**

BTW, the main reason I ask this, is because of this:
[angular.noop](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.noop)

```
function foo(callback) {
  var result = calculateResult();
  (callback || angular.noop)(result);
}
```

It didn't use any `return` which I learned first in coding javascript functions.

Comment: What don't you understand? Are you asking what `return` means?

Comment: Do you have the code for `$someCustomService`? If so, does it have any interest in the return value of the callbacks when it invokes them? It's not so much a matter of style as it is a matter of API semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback functions typically return nothing, they're of type `void` so to say. Neither the `success` and `error` methods care what the callbacks return, nor do you. Whether you pass the result through does not make any difference, it's `undefined` anyway in your case.

Therefore, use the shorter solution without any `return`.

Sometimes you still will see callbacks that use `return`, but only for [helping with control flow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36707/1048572). Assuming an error case doesn't pass data, you might for example write

```
$anotherCustomService.login(function(success, data){
    if(!success)
        return alert('Fail');
//      ^^^^^^
    alert('Success');
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: The link is so helpful. I was thinking if there is any effect on memory management when using or not using `return`.